# Is incomplete testing versus exhaustive analysis an apples-to-oranges comparison?

Tags: alloy

I often hear arguments like this: A disadvantage of traditional testing is that it is incomplete whereas Alloy analysis is exhaustive and complete (within a bound). But, the first is talking about software, the second is talking about models. Isn't it an apples-to-oranges comparison?

**Update**: I was wrong. The comparison is not this: `testing code versus analyzing models`. That is an apples-to-oranges comparison. Instead, the comparisons are these:

```
Testing models versus analysis of models.

Testing code versus analysis of code.
```

Those are apples-to-apples comparisons.

So, whether the artifact is a model or code, you can compare two kinds of analysis: testing, which corresponds to drawing a relatively small number of cases randomly, without a bound on the size, versus small scope analysis, which involves all cases within a small bound.

Thanks to Daniel Jackson for clearing up my misunderstanding.

Comment: You're right. But the quest is to slightly genetically modify the apples and the oranges so we can compare them :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, when Alloy was invented, the only existing tools for analyzing models in data-rich languages such as Z and VDM that were not proof-based used scenarios to test the model. Each scenario was constructed by the user, so the approach suffered from the cost of creating the scenarios and the low coverage of their small number.

Second, Alloy has been used to find bugs in code: see the PhD theses by Mandana Vaziri, Mana Taghdiri, Greg Dennis, Juan Pablo Galeotti and others. In all of these, bugs were found that evaded conventional tests.

Third, it's worth noting that bounded-exhaustive forms of testing are becoming viable. Sarfraz Khurshid was a pioneer in this work with his thesis on generating test cases, initially in a tool called TestEra based on Alloy, and later (with Darko Marinov et al) in a tool called Korat that traded a more diected solving method for less declarative constraints.